# Should I or shouldn't I use refresh tokens with Password Grant authorization in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

If I have a single page web application with a Laravel back end, my best option for authentication seems to be Passport with a Password Grant authentication flow. In Passport, this returns an access token and a refresh token.

For security, I would like to issue a short lived access token and refresh it when it expires. However, all the available information about using OAuth with a Javascript application says "don't make your refresh token accessible to the front end" because it's long-lived and can be used by others to generate new access tokens.

[For example](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current):

> A Single-Page Application (normally implementing Implicit Flow) should
>   not ever receive a Refresh Token. A Refresh Token is essentially a
>   user credential that allows a user to remain authenticated
>   indefinitely. This sensitive information should be stored securely and
>   not exposed client-side in a browser.

Does this mean that a browser-based SPA cannot use refresh tokens and must, therefore, only issue access tokens that expire after a reasonable "session" length, forcing the user to log in again afterwards?

Otherwise, is there a suitable way to implement short-lifespan access tokens and refresh tokens in a Laravel Passport app with Password Grant authentication, while maintaining good security?

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in storing refresh token, as they can be used to get another access token after the access token(short lived as you mentioned) expires which create a good user experience.